# Passing the result of the variable to another variable

Tags: arduino-mega, rfid

Hello everyone i'm figuring if this variable can be passed to another variable. I'm using RFID RC522
Here is the code:

```
 #include <SPI.h>
    #include <MFRC522.h>
    #define RST_PIN         5           // Configurable, see typical pin layout 
    above
    #define SS_PIN          53          // Configurable, see typical pin layout 
    above
    MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.
    int result = 0;
    // Number of known default keys (hard-coded)
    // NOTE: Synchronize the NR_KNOWN_KEYS define with the defaultKeys[] array
    #define NR_KNOWN_KEYS   8
    // Known keys, see: 
    https://code.google.com/p/mfcuk/wiki/MifareClassicDefaultKeys
    byte knownKeys[NR_KNOWN_KEYS][MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE] =  {
    {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, // FF FF FF FF FF FF = factory default
    {0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5}, // A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
    {0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5}, // B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
    {0x4d, 0x3a, 0x99, 0xc3, 0x51, 0xdd}, // 4D 3A 99 C3 51 DD
    {0x1a, 0x98, 0x2c, 0x7e, 0x45, 0x9a}, // 1A 98 2C 7E 45 9A
    {0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7}, // D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7
    {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff}, // AA BB CC DD EE FF
    {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}  // 00 00 00 00 00 00
    };
    /*
    * Initialize.
    */
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);         // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);            // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added 
    for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();                // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();         // Init MFRC522 card
    // Serial.println(F("Try the most used default keys to print block 0 of a 
    MIFARE PICC."));
    }
    /*
    * Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
    */
    void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
        Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}

/*
 * Try using the PICC (the tag/card) with the given key to access block 0.
 * On success, it will show the key details, and dump the block data on Serial.
 *
 * @return true when the given key worked, false otherwise.
 */
boolean try_key(MFRC522::MIFARE_Key *key)
{
    boolean result = false;
    byte buffer[18];
    byte block = 0;
    byte status;

    // Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return false;
    }

    // Read block
    byte byteCount = sizeof(buffer);
    status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer, &byteCount);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    }
    else {
        // Successful read
        result = true;
        //Serial.print(F("Success with key:"));
        dump_byte_array((*key).keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
        //Serial.println();
        // Dump block data
       // Serial.print(F("Block ")); Serial.print(block); Serial.print(F(":"));
        dump_byte_array(buffer, 16);
        //Serial.println();
    }
  //  Serial.println();

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();       // Halt PICC
    mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD
    return result;
}

/*
 * Main loop.
 */
void loop() {
  // Look for new cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
        return;
// Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    return;
    // Show some details of the PICC (that is: the tag/card)
   // Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
    dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
delay(3000); 
// Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
  //  byte piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
    //Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

    // Try the known default keys

      }
```

I list all of my card's value and i want to create a conditional statement if the result of dump_byte_array is the same with my card's value i list.
Sample:

```
if ( dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size) && "D4 39 F8 BE" == 
  true ){
        Serial.print("Card 1 Detected");
```

That's what i want to happen but i know that is wrong.
Please help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code, not just snippets. Minimal means you've stripped away irrelevant stuff, just leaving what's needed to show the problem. Complete means all the library names are shown, all the variable declarations, and all the function definitions – so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant. Verifiable means it can be compiled and tested, allowing other people to test their theories about the problem

Comment: Ok sir , i will edit my post.

Comment: looks similar to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/49962/dump-byte-arraymfrc522-uid-uidbyte-mfrc522-uid-size) - anyway, since the function (which you wrote) i.e. `void dump_byte_array` doesn't return anything, then, no, you can't possibly compare the result of calling that function with anything ... perhaps create a new function, to which you pass `mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size, [0xD4, 0x39, 0xf8, oxbe]` which can return true/false

Comment: I tried to add this code and it works fine but no result if its, Card 1 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `dump_byte_array` is a void function, so you can't compare it to anything.

And this line

```
if (dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size) && "D4 39 F8 BE" == true)
```

is both ilegal and illogical. Ilegal, because you are comparing a pointer ("
("D4 39 F8 BE") against an integer (the *true* value is a int in disguise).

It's illogical, because you are "&&" is the **logical and** operator, not the bitwise *and*.

What you need is a string comparison:

```
if (strncmp(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, "D4 39 F8 BE", mfrc522.uid.size) == 0) {
   Serial.println("Card found");
}
```

That's assuming that uidByte contains the ID.

**The strncmp function**

```
int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );
```

*Compare characters of two strings*

Compares up to num characters of the C string str1 to those of the C string str2.

This function starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ, until a terminating null-character is reached, or until num characters match in both strings, whichever happens first.

*Parameters*

str1     C string to be compared.

str2     C string to be compared.

num      Maximum number of characters to compare. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

*Return Value*

Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:

- <0   the first character that does not match has a lower value in str1
  than in str2
- 0    the contents of both strings are equal
- >0  the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2

But you really need to learn C.

Comment: Judging by the (rather confusing) question the array in question is "binary" (not a string) so `strncmp` might easily fail if there was 0x00 in the array. Probably `memcmp` would be more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Simply rewrite your dump_byte_array function as follows

```
bool matchID(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize, byte * match, byte matchSize) {
    if (bufferSize != matchSize) return false;
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
        if (buffer[i] != match[i]) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

and call this new function like

```
if ( matchID(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size, [0xD4, 0x39, 0xF8, 0xBE], 4)) {
    Serial.print("Card 1 Detected");
}
```

As suggested in the comments, what's wrong with memcmp ...

```
bool matchID(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize, byte * match, byte matchSize) {
    if (bufferSize != matchSize) return false;
    return memcmp(buffer, match, bufferSize) == 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite this:
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);

Comment: to this:
[code]
bool matchID(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize, byte * match, byte matchSize) {
if (bufferSize <> matchSize) return false;
for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
 if (buffer[i] <> match[i]) 
return falsbool matchID(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize, byte * match, byte matchSize) {
 if (bufferSize <> matchSize) return false;
 for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
if (buffer[i] <> match[i]) 
return false;
    return true;
};
    return true;
}
[/code]

Comment: And it gives me:
exit status 1
expected primary-expression before '>' token

Comment: That's not valid code. Sorry was in vb mode

Comment: But it can convert it to C++ ?

Comment: answer edited, check now - my code had one flaw ... `<>` instead of `!=` - so, yes, it can be converted!

Comment: It gives me another error:expected primary-expression before '>' token

Comment: see ... there were **two** places I used `<>` instead of `!=` - that's the problem with blindly copying code from an answer without understanding it - try now - I'm beginning to suspect the code in the question is not written by you, rather it is an exact copy of someone elses efforts

Comment: I didn't copy paste the code, i'm typing it and trying to understand what's the code mean.

Comment: What's wrong with using `memcmp`?

Comment: absolutely nothing - just made the simplest change possible with the view that it'd be easier to learn :p added it to the answer